# In Worklight client devices forget their notification subscriptions

Tags: notifications, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a button in my Worklight app which subscribes the app and user to a notification source in much the same way as the Notification sample at this URL: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced

The problem is that when the device restarts / or the app shuts and I need to relogin - the isSubscribed function will return false - despite previously being true.

Is the client side meant to automatically save its subscriptions? What is the best practice for maintaining a subscription to a notification source across multiple device / app restarts?

This is my securityTests setup :

```
<securityTests>
        <customSecurityTest name="WebServicesAdapters-securityTest">
            <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="CustomAuthenticatorRealm"/>
        </customSecurityTest>

          <mobileSecurityTest name="PushApplication-strong-mobile-securityTest">
            <testUser realm="CustomAuthenticatorRealm"/>
            <testDeviceId provisioningType="none"/>
        </mobileSecurityTest>

    </securityTests>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure here... but, are you certain that you are using the same realm?

Comment: The same realm as what?

Comment: Andy, forget about my previous comment; I have asked around - this is a defect in v5.0.5.x, fixed in 5.0.6 (to work around it you can try using authentication that is not adapter-based. This will fail if protecting only the adapter, the application must be protected as well). As said, this is fixed in 5.0.6.

Answer (score 0):

This is a defect in Worklight v5.0.5.x, fixed in 5.0.6.

To work around it you can try using authentication that is not adapter-based. This will fail if protecting only the adapter, the application must be protected as well.